# Why are Exceptions iterable?

Tags: exception, python-2.x

I have been bitten by something unexpected recently. I wanted to make something like that:

```
try :
     thing.merge(iterable) # this is an iterable so I add it to the list
except TypeError :
     thing.append(iterable) # this is not iterable, so I add it
```

Well, It was working fine until I passed an object inheriting from Exception which was supposed to be added.

Unfortunetly, an Exception is iterable. The following code does not raise any `TypeError`:

```
for x in Exception() :
    print 1
```

Does anybody know why?

Comment: I re-tagged this because the behaviour is Python 2.x specific. In 3.x, exceptions are **not** iterable and you will get a `TypeError` explicitly telling you so (after adjusting the `print` syntax, of course).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that what is happening is not related to any kind of implicit string conversion etc, but because the `Exception` class implements `__getitem__` to return the values from the args tuple (`ex.args`). You can see this by the fact that you get the whole string as your first and only item in the iteration, rather than the character-by-character result you'd get if you iterate over the string.

This surprised me too, but thinking about it, I'm guessing it is for backwards compatibility reasons.  Python used to ([pre-1.5](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/stdexceptions.html)) lack the current class hierarchy of exceptions.  Instead, strings were thrown, with (usually) a tuple argument for any details that should be passed to the handling block, i.e:

```
try:
    raise "something failed", (42, "some other details")
except "something failed", args:
    errCode, msg = args
    print "something failed.  error code %d: %s" % (errCode, msg)
```

It looks like this behavior was put in to avoid breaking pre-1.5 code expecting a tuple of arguments, rather than a non-iterable exception object.  There are a couple of examples of this with `IOError` in the Fatal Breakage section of the above [link](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/stdexceptions.html)

String exceptions have been deprecated for a while, and are gone in Python 3. Exception objects are no longer iterable in Python 3:

```
>>> list(Exception("test"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Exception' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Brillant ! Thx for the explanation. I'l like to accept the answer but it seems like we need some more vote up before I am allowed to.

Comment: The links are broken.  Can you update them?

Answer (score 2):

NOT VALID. Check Brian anwser.

Ok, I just got it :

```
for x in Exception("test") :
    print x
   ....:     
   ....:     
test
```

Don't bother ;-)

Anyway, it's good to know.

EDIT : looking to the comments, I feel like adding some explanations.

An exception contains a message you passed to during instantiation :

```
raise Exception("test") 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: test
```

It's fair to say that the message is what defines the Exception the best, so str() returns it :

```
print Exception("test") 
test
```

Now, it happens that Exceptions are implicitly converted to string when used in something else than an Exception context.

So when I do :

```
for x in Exception("test") :
    print x
```

I am iterating over the string "test".

And when I do :

```
for x in Exception() :
    print x
```

I do iterate over an empty string. Tricky. Because when it comes to my issue :

```
try :
    thing.merge(ExceptionLikeObject)
except TypeError :
    ...
```

This won't raise anything since ExceptionLikeObject is considered as a string.

Well now, we know the HOW, but I still not the WHY. Maybe the built-in Exception inherit from the built-in String ? Because as far as I know :

- adding **str** does not make any object iterable.
- I bypassed the problem by overloding **iter**, making it raising TypeError !

Not a problem anymore, but still a mystery.

Comment: Actually it's not treating it as a string, it's treating it as the argument tuple.  ie list(Exception("test")) == ["test"], not ["t","e","s","t"].  Similarly list(Exception(1,2)) == [1, 2].  See my answer below for some speculation as to why this may be.