# How to destructure exception in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, destructuring

This code:

```
try:
    raise ValueError(1,2,3)
except ValueError as (a,b,c):
    print("a=%s, b=%s, c=%s" % (a,b,c))
```

prints `a=1, b=2, c=3` in Python 2, but raises a `SyntaxError` in Python 3:

```
    except ValueError as (a,b,c):
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**How do I destructure exceptions in Python 3?**

The following seems to work (inspired by the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)):

```
try:
    raise ValueError(1,2,3)
except ValueError as ex:
    a,b,c = ex.args
    print("a=%s, b=%s, c=%s" % (a,b,c))
```

but is ugly (and  adds an extra line of code), which is a PITA when converting codebase 2to3.

Comment: Is this for a code golf? (I see no other reason why that extra line of code is a problem...)

Comment: `print("..." % ex.args)` would work find if you worried about line count.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ If converting from Python 2 to Python 3, this could be a real pain across a big code base. Since this particular syntax is not clearly addressed by the PEP that specified the use of `as` for Python 3, it makes it even more painful. (This [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/) only seems to discuss getting rid of the old-style comma separation for purposes of catching multiple exception types, and doesn't discuss automatically unpacking the exception in-line).

Comment: Frankly, I was surprised to learn that exceptions *were* iterable. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/258930/1126841), it was a hack to accommodate the old-old-style string exceptions.